# THREE.js BufferGeometry index size

Tags: three.js

Does `THREE.BufferGeometry` currently support 32-bit index buffers? WebGL 1.0 doesn't, unless extension "OES_element_index_uint" is explicitly enabled. But is this somehow implemented in THREE.js by default? I could not find information about this anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[you could look at the source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a539d00955007ef5aebb9b393ab77569c0d51d4e/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L275) and see that yes, three.js [supports 32bit index buffers](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a539d00955007ef5aebb9b393ab77569c0d51d4e/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLIndexedBufferRenderer.js)

Then you could look at [webglstats.com](http://webglstats.com/) and see it claims 98% of devices support that extension. You could also probably reason that any device that doesn't support that extension is probably old and underpowered and not worth worrying about.

TLDR; Yes, Three.js supports 32-bit index buffers